# How to make Button for inserting text only in selected texbox

Tags: selected

Good morning.

I have 10 texboxs (texbox1, textbox2, ...., textbox10), also I have a button that will give a text "Boby" when it's clcked.

But I have a problem and pretty confusing. I want the button only write "Boby" on the textbox where the cursor's located.

For instance: I put the cursor on textbox1, then I press the button, "Boby" will appear on textbox1. Then, if I put cursor on textbox4 and I click the button, the writing "Boby" will appear on textbox4.

I have asked about this to many friend and googling for 2 days but I could not find the answer.

Comment: which technology you are using???

Comment: Edit and add tag for language and technology.

Comment: This looks like you're using C#, correct? Is this a Winforms app? WPF? Asp.Net?

Answer (score 1):

find an event that is triggered when one of the textboxes receives focus and remember which one was it in a variable. then when you press the button set the text of the textbox from the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what @ZdravkoDanev suggested.

Assuming you're using a C# Winforms application:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.GotFocus += new EventHandler(TextBoxGotFocus);
        textBox2.GotFocus += new EventHandler(TextBoxGotFocus);
        textBox3.GotFocus += new EventHandler(TextBoxGotFocus);
        //and so on
    }

    TextBox t = null;
    private void TextBoxGotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox t = sender as TextBox;
        this.t = t;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(t != null)
            t.Text = "boby";
    }
}
```

Bear in mind that the first text box may receive focus by default when the form appears, so clicking the button will add "Boby" to it. If you do not want this behavior, use the text boxes' `Click` event instead of the `GotFocus` event.